# Access your PC from Mobile

Tags: .net

Is it poosible to acccess data(Videos,Pics etc) on PC from Mobile? , if yes how can I create this .net application. any guidence will be really helpful or anu free tool I can use ?? I know this is not a place, but I am looking for person to share knowledge who worked on such type of work

Comment: What type of data are you looking to access?

Comment: Not sure this is the best place for this question. You could use drop box or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Which mobile operating system?

If the PC is accessbible over the internet, then the answer is yes. Mobile phones typically have internet access and can access the PC as easily as any other server on the internet.

So your question needs to be more specific. What kind of data are you accessing, what do you want to do with it, etc? It's less of a question about mobile and PCs that it is about remote access to computers generally.